# Can an iPhone 5S play music that's stored on a USB drive?

Tags: iphone, usb, music

My wife's iPhone 5S doesn't have enough storage space for all of her music.  If we were to buy a USB drive that connects to her phone, could we put her music on that and then have the phone play it from there in a reasonably hassle-free way?  What would the process be?

Comment: I don't...think so? You can totally do this with an Android phone, but...

Comment: I recommend you just use a streaming service like Apple Music, Spotify, YouTube, etc. which can take up next-to-no space and give you access to any songs whenever.

Comment: Anyway, I've posted a full answer now, let me know if it solves your question, and please comment if you need anything else!

Comment: There are also products like the [Sandisk Connect Wireless Media Drive](https://www.sandisk.com/home/mobile-device-storage/connect-wireless-media-drive) or the [WD My Passport Wireless](https://www.wdc.com/products/portable-storage/my-passport-wireless.html), which let you access media (via their respective apps) without something hanging from the phone but at the cost of more WiFi connections to manage and batteries to charge. If you can use WiFi or unlimited cellular data, I'd go for Apple Music or [iTunes Match](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204146).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* read a flash from an iOS device, but this capability is limited to some very fancy lightning-port enabled USB flash drives.

For most use cases, I would recommend using a cloud service like Google Drive if you're looking to listen to purchased music on an iPhone without using up storage space. Essentially, you can just drag your music purchased from anywhere into Google Drive, download [the app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-drive-free-online-storage/id507874739?mt=8) onto your iPhone, sign into your account, and listen to your music (though you of course need an internet connection unless you download them to your phone).

However, if you want to buy a special flash drive, you can purchase the [Sandisk iXpand Flash Drive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CIEBU22), which plugs directly into the lightning port and [can play music](http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/18915/~/playing-music-with-the-ixpand-drive-app) while plugged into the iPhone, through the Sandisk iXpand app. Just connect it to a Mac/PC beforehand to load music onto it through the standard USB port.

[image]

**tl;dr:** Buy [this flash drive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CIEBU22) or use [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com).

---

**Edit:** don't forget about streaming services like Spotify and Apple Music, which don't take up storage space either.

Comment: Another great choice for streaming your own music is Microsoft Groove. It allows you to play music from your OneDrive.

Comment: @בנימןהגלילי Good point, I haven't tried Groove but I hear it's great.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use a USB drive but do this with a [My Passport Wireless Pro drive](https://www.wdc.com/products/portable-storage/my-passport-wireless-pro.html#WDBVPL0010BBK-NESN). The iPhone connects to the My Passport through the Passport's Wi-Fi and the My Cloud app gives me access to all the music and audio books we own. The only issue I have is that I can't give the media player commands through Siri. Honestly if Siri doesn't start to learn the way Alexa does my next phone won't be an Apple.

If I didn't use the My Passport for other things it wouldn't be worth it, but at this point I still have a need for external storage.